# Flutter: I would like to scroll the ListView after the main SingleChildScrollView Scroll end

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I have a ListView.builder wrapped with a SingleChildScrollView, and each has its scroll, so when I click at the ListView it only scroll the ListView without Scroll the SingleChildScrollView, and my ListView is dynamic so I can't use physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() because it disable my ListVeiw.builder

I want to Scroll the main screen which has some widgets and the ListView, builder in the middle and in last has a bottom

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Carrinho",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontFamily: 'Inter'),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 400,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/cover.jpg'),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 60),
                        Text(
                          "MEU CESTO",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontFamily: 'Inter'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: 80,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: sGreenColour,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(children: [
                        Text(
                          "ITENS: ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                        Text("$itemsQtd",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16))
                      ]),
                      Row(children: [
                        Text("TOTAL: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18)),
                        Text("$totalValue MT",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18))
                      ])
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,

                // HERE MY ListView.buider
                child: CartProducts( 
                  cart_list: cart_list,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 15,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text("$totalValue MT",
                            style: TextStyle(color: sGreenColour)),
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                              sGreenLightColour),
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 15,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          "TERMINAR",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                              side: BorderSide(color: sGreenColour),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

and my ListView.builder

```
class _CartProductsState extends State<CartProducts> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // Disable Scroll
        itemCount: widget.cart_list.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return SigleProduct(
            name: widget.cart_list[index]["name"],
            picture: widget.cart_list[index]["picture"],
            price: widget.cart_list[index]["price"],
            unit: widget.cart_list[index]["unit"],
          );
        });
  }
}

// THE ELEMENT OF THE GRIDVIEW
class SigleProduct extends StatelessWidget {
  SigleProduct({this.name, this.picture, this.price, this.unit})
      : super(key: null);

  final name;
  final picture;
  final price;
  final unit;

  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, int id) {
    // set up the buttons
    Widget cancelButton = TextButton(
      child: Text("Não"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
      },
    );
    Widget continueButton = TextButton(
      child: Text(
        "Sim",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dismiss dialog
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text("Producto Removido!"),
        ));
      },
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Center(child: Text("Alerta!")),
      content: Text("Gostaria de Remover o producto do carrinho?"),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        continueButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 2,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          onTap: () {},
          leading: Container(
            width: 80,
            //color: Colors.amber,
            child: Image.asset(picture),
          ),
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 14)),
              Text("$price MT",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: sGreenColour,
                      fontSize: 14)),
            ],
          ),
          subtitle: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text('Unit: $price MT/$unit',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45)),
                  Text('Qtd: 2/$unit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45)),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 25,
                    width: 110,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        showAlertDialog(context, 1);
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "REMOVER",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 25,
                    width: 110,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text("ACTUALIZAR",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white))),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          selected: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please Help